# Remote Desktop Ubuntu22.04.2 and MacBook M1

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, macbook, remote-access

I have an Ubuntu 22.04.2 version installed over an old MacBook Pro 2011 installed.
I'm trying to connect from a MacBook Air M1 and I can reach my Ubuntu computer and see the message

```
Do you want to share your desktop?
A user on the computer [...] is trying to remotely view or control your desktop
```

When I click on Accept and introduce my password in the MacBook Air computer I'm having the following error.

```
Connexion error with name.local

It's not possible to communicate with "name.local".
Please be sure that the remote computer is available and
that there isn't any firewall that blocks the screen share.
```

I've got the Legacy VNC Protocol enable.
The firewall status is disabled.

I've checked many different solutions but I don't find the correct one.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question and add the exact info you are using on the computer that is trying to connect. Also the exact info on the machine you are trying to access. Pay special attention to the names been used.